# How to get url out of the style tag using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to get this url out of this line but i have no idea how to get it :-

```
<div class="photo" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://images.deliveryhero.io/image/fd-bd/Products/1032643.jpg?width=200&quot;);"></div>
```

it is inside this :-

```
<picture data-testid="menu-product-image" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://micro-assets.foodora.com/img/logo-simple-fp.svg&quot;);"><div class="photo" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://images.deliveryhero.io/image/fd-bd/Products/1032643.jpg?width=200&quot;);"></div></picture>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
url = driver.find_element_by_class_name("photo").value_of_css_property("background-image")[9:-2]
```